MySQL query shows different result in server
My Localhost is MySQL 8.2.0 while ther server is MariaDB 10.1.30.
db-fiddle
This is my query:
SELECT
  adc.que,
  a.adname,
  a.adidentify,
  adc.loc,
  spa.aname,
  adc.qty,
  adc.var1,
  COUNT(ls.up_device) AS usage_count,
  MAX(lstp.stopdate) AS last_stop_date
FROM
  a_device a
  JOIN a_device_cons adc ON a.adid = adc.devid
  JOIN log_station ls ON FIND_IN_SET(
    ls.up_device,
    REPLACE(a.adidentify, '|', ',')
  ) > 0
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      devid,
      consid,
      consloc,
      MAX(stopdate) AS stopdate
    FROM
      log_stop
    WHERE
      consid IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      devid,
      consid,
      consloc
  ) AS max_stopdate ON adc.devid = max_stopdate.devid
  AND adc.aid = max_stopdate.consid
  AND adc.loc = max_stopdate.consloc
  JOIN log_stop lstp ON adc.devid = lstp.devid
  AND adc.aid = lstp.consid
  AND adc.loc = lstp.consloc
  AND max_stopdate.stopdate = lstp.stopdate
  JOIN sp_asset spa ON spa.aid = lstp.consid
WHERE
  ls.up_date > lstp.stopdate
GROUP BY
  lstp.devid,
  lstp.consid,
  lstp.consloc;

a_device sample data:



adid
adname
adidentify




hDix3NT20240423
TEST400X_D3.0_CALIBRATION_02
TEST4003CH2_100002_B|TEST4004TC1_100002_B|TEST4004TC2_100002_B



a_device_cons sample data:



devid
aid
qty
loc
var1




hDix3NT20240423
741
1
LOC_1
8000


hDix3NT20240423
434
1
LOC_1
8000


hDix3NT20240423
947
1
LOC_1
8000


hDix3NT20240423
2146
2
LOC_1
8000



log_station sample data:



up_date
up_device




2024-04-23 19:25:55
TEST4004TC2_100002_B


2024-04-23 19:19:22
TEST4004TC2_100002_B



log_stop sample data:



devid
consid
consloc
stopdate




hDix3NT20240423
741
LOC_1
2024-04-23 17:24:18


hDix3NT20240423
434
LOC_1
2024-04-23 17:24:18


hDix3NT20240423
947
LOC_1
2024-04-23 17:24:18


hDix3NT20240423
2146
LOC_1
2024-04-23 17:24:18



MySQL Query Result:



que
adname
adidentify
loc
aname
qty
var1
usage_count
last_stop_date




35
TETS400X_D3.0_CALIBRATION_02
TEST4003CH2_100002_B|TEST4004TC1_100002_B|TEST4004TC2_100002_B
LOC_1
CABLE TEIPHONE
2
8000
2
2024-04-23 17:24:18


34
TEST400X_D3.0_CALIBRATION_02
TEST4003CH2_100002_B|TEST4004TC1_100002_B|TEST4004TC2_100002_B
LOC_1
QUICK CONNECTOR| Needle spacing 2.2~2.4mm| inner diameter 0.9mm
1
8000
2
2024-04-23 17:24:18


33
TEST400X_D3.0_CALIBRATION_02
TEST4003CH2_100002_B|TEST4004TC1_100002_B|TEST4004TC2_100002_B
LOC_1
ETHERNET EXTENSION CABLE BLACK 30CM
1
8000
2
2024-04-23 17:24:18


32
TEST400X_D3.0_CALIBRATION_02
TEST4003CH2_100002_B|TEST4004TC1_100002_B|TEST4004TC2_100002_B
LOC_1
DC CABLE POWER F-N-OT ADAPTER 2C
1
8000
2
2024-04-23 17:24:18



MariaDB Query Result:



que
adname
adidentify
loc
aname
qty
var1
usage_count
last_stop_date




35
TETS400X_D3.0_CALIBRATION_02
TEST4003CH2_100002_B|TEST4004TC1_100002_B|TEST4004TC2_100002_B
LOC_1
CABLE TEIPHONE
2
8000
2
2024-04-23 17:24:18



The query fetches the result I want in localhost (MySQL) by showing 4 rows which are the Consumable Usage count for each combination of a Device and a Consumable ID (aid/consid).
Yet somehow after exporting the database to the server (MariaDB). The query gets different result by only displaying 1 row.

Lesson no. 1: always develop / test in the same environment you intend to deploy to

First thing to consider enable sql_mode only_full_group_by. If enabled you will be faced by some errors after fixing the errors let us know if the problem persist.

There is one table and some columns referenced in your query but missing from the sample data. I suggest you create a dbfiddle with a reproducible case, so folks reading your post can test the query.

Provide sample data not as textual tables but as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

It would help debugging if you included the grouping columns in the SELECT list.

There is no mysql v8.2. There is mysql v8.3, which is an experimental, unstable version. v8.0.x are the production versions. Which one do you use?

@Shadow 8.2.0 is still showing in the MySQL archives - https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/

@user1191247 then the OP is using a discontinued version of mysql, which may be even worse...

I made a db-fiddle link link. I received this error message with my original query Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.adc.que' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. The query you see in that link is a revised one. @BillKarwin

I still get the result I want in db-fiddle. After testing the new query in the server, unfortunately the result is still different. Any idea what to do or where to start from?

I tested in MariaDB 10.3 and it seems to work correctly (result is 4 rows). I suggest upgrade MariaDB to a version that isn't so old, or switch to current MySQL. You are using MariaDB 10.1, which was past its end of life in 2020.

if it wasn't clear, mysql 8.2 was a development version and should not be used; delete it.  you should install the same version of mariadb as you have in production.  but do verify what server version you have by doing select version();; it's easy to be misled to think a client version is your server version.

Perhaps a confusion over MAX(stopdate)?
